# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable.ExecuteBatchAsync() truncates message

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

When I call this method with large EntityProperty (around 17Kb of text), it truncates the string.

I know that there is a limitation of 64Kb for a column and 1Mb for 1 entire row when it comes to Azure Table.

Any insights?

Comment: We gave this a try and it works as expected. Which version of the Storage client library are you using? Can you please provide us details about how you create the entity? It would help us if you could share a code snippet that reproes this problem and a fiddler trace showing the batch operation where the data was truncated. You can send an email with these details to veudayab@microsoft.com if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from all these size restrictions, you forgot about the size restriction in an entity group transaction which is done by `ExecuteBatchAsync` method and that is:

> The transaction can include at most 100 entities, and its total
>   payload may be no more than **4 MB** in size.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd894038.aspx

Please ensure that your payload size is less than 4 MB.

Comment: Ok. I have only one TableOperation in the TableBatchOperation which is an input to ExecuteBatchAsync(...). So in that case, why it truncates 17Kb of data?

Comment: My bad. I just assumed that when you're performing entity batch operation, you have more than one entity. When you say the data is truncated, you meant the entity property's text is truncated. Am I correct?